# Path Matching for Journeys Using XY Coordinates

Tags: r, geometry, route, trajectory, similarity

I am trying to find some suggestions on ways or algorithms to determine path similarity. An illustration of 3 paths using made up data is given below. The title should be finding similar paths instead of calculating distance.

[image: Finding Similar Paths]

As you can see in the figure that there are two bus routes and one user journey. The original data will contain latitude/longitude coordinates. The journeys could be polylines/polygons/more complex shapes with or without intersections. I want to ask a few things:

1. Can frechet distance be used to find similarity between paths instead of between different points of a path or trajectory?
2. Do a path and trajectory mean the same thing?
3. Can we use frechet distance for polylines, polygonal curves and other shapes e.g., polylines with curves?
4. Can frechet distance handle intersections like present in the figure?
5. Are there other better methods of calculating path similarity?

The goal is to find a similar path within a given threshold of a user journey. let's say if there is/are route within 25 meters of the user path, then find how similar that route is to the user journey.

Comment: I think there are too many questions and too much possibility of discussion to make a generally useful answer here.